# OAuth2 Implicit flow vs 'Traditional' session based auth for small SPA

Tags: session, authentication, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, single-page-application

Some background:
I am writing a small SPA that will use a back end that I have also written. The JS and the back end API are on the same server.

i.e. SPA will load from foo.com, back end is at foo.com/api

In the past I have always used Spring Security with simple form based login. After logging in the user will get a session cookie. Pretty standard stuff.

For this app I looked into OAuth2 implicit flow. My understanding is the User would load my page, then from the SPA I would direct the user to the authorization endpoint so my app could get a token. The user would be redirected from the authorization endpoint to a login form. After the user authenticated with the form.. they would be redirected back to the authorization endpoint to get the token and possibly grant access to the JS client. After that the user would be redirected to a URL specified by the client, with the new access token as a URL fragment.

I have this working and its all great. The part I don't quite get is this:
When the user is redirected to the login form and they authenticate a session is created on the server that has to at least last long enough for the user to be redirected to the authorization endpoint to get the token. At that point they already have an authenticated session on my server, why not just stop there and use traditional cookie and session based logins?